# Has anyone tried making their own make-shift Hydrapack?

Tags: diy

Has anyone tried making their own make-shift Hydrapack?
Over the years of trekking I have never owned a Hydrapack. So, before investing on something, and for some fun-n-learn part of it, I would like to make myself a Hydrapack. What are the basic things that I need, and how to go about it?
I first had a thought of making it out of Blood-bags or Urine bags that are used in hospitals.

I have always tried to make things for fun. Like I made my own Headlamp using power LEDs and a cheap circuit, which honestly works as good as a Petzl lamp. That urge to use make-my-own-gear products really has made me understand the product more and repair/make-shift them in case of emergencies. I have made a swiss-knife out of something as well, that's the point: Fun-n-make.

Comment: Considering I can by one for less than a couple of cups of coffee I'd rather not rely for hydration on something that might break when I need it.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I think Weda was more inclined towards fun-n-learn part of making a hydrapack than using it in critical situations.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Agree sir, But like I said, *I first had a thought of using Urine bag or Blood bag.* True it wont carry much of water/fluid. But if I can make something which could carry a couple of litres then it would be so much fun.

Comment: I think it could be a fun project and have upvoted you... but I still would not use one in real life:-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Indeed, I won't seriously take it on a hike either. But, I would love to take one such thing for something like a little photography session, not lasting for more than a couple of hours. I can afford a real hydrapack of course, but as I said, the fun part! I believe you must have gone through this phase in your life as well when you try to engineer things out of something!

Comment: You mean my city wine-pack?

Comment: @Vorac: What is a City Wine-pack?

Comment: @WedaPashi, take a hydration bladder, fill it with wine and carry it around the city in the backpack. Now you don't need to stop the bike in order to drink alcohol :) I haven't tried it actually, but [intend to](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5677/dringking-water-plastic-can-i-store-beer-in-this).

Answer (score 4):

There was a TV show called SAS Survival Secrets a few years back and one of the guys carried a regular condom in his emergency pack and showed how he could use it as an emergency hydration pack/bottle.  I think he was able to put about 2L of water in it.

Comment: More importantly, does it blend?